# docker run --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE gets "invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase"

Tags: docker

How can I use `--cap-add=[NAME_IN_UPPERCASE]`?

I was trying to run a docker container with following command:

```
docker run -d \
       -p:8991:8999 \
       --name myname \
       --network quiznet \
       --link redis_redis_1:redis \
       -v /data:/data \
       --log-opt max-size=500m \
       –-cap-add=SYS_PTRACE \
       my_lowercase_image_name
```

and I found out that `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` caused the error:

> docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.

but in the offical doc [Runtime privilege and Linux capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) it seems okay to use `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` in the official example as follow:

> ```
> $ docker run -it --rm --cap-add=NET_ADMIN ubuntu:14.04 ip link add dummy0 type dummy
> ```

My docker version is:

```
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
```

Answer (score 2):

just run it like so:

```
docker run -d --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE -p 8991:8999 .....
```

notice no `:` after the `p` parameter

Comment: The port option has the format `-p IP:host_port:container_port` or `-p IP::port`.  `-p:8991:8999` seems to be valid as well. If the IP is empty docker defaults to meta-address `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

I ran the exact command you posted and the problem seems to be the `–-` in front of `–-cap-add` which is not a double minus. It is instead a dash followed by a minus.

`–` is U+2013 : EN DASH

`-` is U+002D : HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen or minus sign}

[What Unicode character is this ?](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html)

Docker doesn't recognize it as a program option and considers `–-cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to be name of the image hence the error.